# How to save a record that has_many other records in EmberJs

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js, coffeescript, many-to-many, ember-data

Please can you help me.

I have a model A:

```
A = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  bs:    DS.hasMany('b', {async: true})
`export default A'
```

and model B:

```
B = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  as:    DS.hasMany('a', {async: true})
'export default B'
```

I can not seem to save A with some Bs.
I tried different things I could have found on SO or around the internet.
But the best thing I accomplished was to get A saved without Bs.

```
someB = here exists loaded from server

a = @store.createRecord 'a', {
  title: 'sth'
}

a.save().then((a) ->
  a.get('bs').then((bs) ->
    bs.pushObject(someB)
    a.save()
  )
  # i tried with a.save() here as well
)
```

So A get saved, but when I want to save A with bs, so that on my server goes PUT/PATCH on `a` with `{bs: [someID]}`

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to make it work, but it is hackish so if someone knows better solution please help.

```
a.save().then((a)=>
  a.get('bs').then((bs)=>
    bs.pushObjects(someBs)

    a.save()
  ).then((a)=>
    a.save()
  )
)
```

As you can see there is one save to many but this is the only way it worked. First save of a sends to server bs: nil, the second one sends bs: [someBID, someOtherBID, ...]